# How to manage items in a list with position

Tags: c#

In an itinerary, you can define a starting point and a destination and also add waypoints.

When adding waypoint, if there are already 1 or more waypoints, the user will be able to choose in which position he wants to place the waypoint, if he does not choose the position will be the last one, when editing the waypoint he will also be able to change his position and when deleting any waypoint the list must be reorganized.

The challenge is how to create this correct management of the waypoints in a list so that at the end of the process I save the list with the organized waypoints. I have never performed complex operations with lists.

[images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9s4BL.png)

```
public class Itinerary : BaseEntity, IAggregateRoot
{
    public Itinerary(int id, Address start, Address end, List<Waypoint> waypoints = null)
    {
        Id = id;
        Start = start;
        End = end;
        _waypoints = waypoints;
    }

    public Itinerary()
    {
    }

    public Address Start { get; set; }
    public Address End { get; set; }

    private readonly List<Waypoint> _waypoints = new List<Waypoint>();
    public IReadOnlyCollection<Waypoint> Waypoints => _waypoints.AsReadOnly().OrderBy(x => x.Position).ToList();

    public List<int> AvailableWaypoints()
    {
        List<int> waypoints = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < _waypoints.Count(); i++)
        {
            waypoints.Add(_waypoints[i].Position);
        }

        return waypoints.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
    }


    public void AddWaypoint(Waypoint waypoint)
    {
        //...
    }

    public void UpdateWaypoint(Waypoint waypoint)
    {
        //...
    }

    public void RemoveWaypoint(Waypoint waypoint)
    {
        //...
    }
}

public class Waypoint : BaseEntity
{
    public Waypoint(int id, Address address, int position, int itineraryId, Itinerary itinerary = null)
    {
        Id = id;
        Address = address;
        Position = position;
        ItineraryId = itineraryId;
        Itinerary = itinerary;
    }

    public Waypoint()
    {
    }

    public Address Address { get; set; }
    public int Position { get; set; }
    public int ItineraryId { get; set; }
    public Itinerary Itinerary { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inserts an element into the List at the specified index. [List.Insert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.insert?view=net-5.0)

With this, maybe you can insert waypoints into the list at the waypoint position. Bare in mind that you will probably need to deal with the fact that indexes begin at 0 and your waypoints positions may begin with 1.

```
_waypoints.Insert(waypoint.Position - 1, waypoint);
```